How to use PhoneNumberField and PhoneNumber in phonenumber_field package?
I'm trying to use the PhoneNumberField and PhoneNumber classes from the phonenumber_field package in my Django project
However, when I try to use those classes in my code, I'm encountering an error. Here's the code snippet where the error occurs:
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from phonenumber_field.phonenumber import PhoneNumber
The error message I'm receiving is: AttributeError: module 'phonenumber_field.modelfields' has no attribute 'PhoneNumberField'
Can someone please guide me on the correct usage of these classes and help me resolve this issue?"
I have already installed the phonenumber_field package and verified that it is up to date
